# CLion install FILES given no DESTINATION

Tags: cmake, clion

I am trying to link ROOT (CERN) to my executable within CLion. I am following instructions available at  https://root.cern.ch/how/integrate-root-my-project-cmake

During the ROOT_GENERATE_DICTIONARY stage cmake complains that 'install FILES given no DESTINATION'. I was able to track this error to the following line:

```
install(FILES ${pcm_name} ${rootmap_name}
                DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} COMPONENT libraries)
```

My ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR} appears to be empty. Why would this be? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Unrelated to CLion, please edit your question and remove the tag.

Comment: Probably CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR is empty, either define it or put qutationmarks around the argument.